# What's the "right" way to do polling in an android service in terms of timing(waiting), wifi and power locking

Tags: android, service, locking, wait, thread-sleep

I have an android app, that gets some information from the internet. Usually it gets it through my server, which collets the data and sends it via GCM, but there is a certain scenario, where it goes into a fallback mode, when it starts a service that polls a 3rd party REST API every 2 seconds. I wonder what's the right way to implement this (pros/cons)

1st way: My 1st implementation was to use an AlarmManager and a BroadcastReceiver. In the BroadcastReceiver I locked PowerManager.WakeLock and WifiManager.WifiLock, then when I got the response I unlocked them, and set up the AlarmManager for 2 seconds.

Then I thought that probably all I achieved by this is that my app hardly shows up as a battery consumer in android Settings, while basically it does drain the battery, as probably the WiFi is not disconnected for 2 seconds, then reconnected. Also noticed that because of the BroadcastReceiver I create a new instance of my RestClient every 2 seconds, then garbage collect it. So I am thinking of changing the implementation:

2nd way: lock PowerManager, WifiManager when I start the PollService (this will cause my app to show up in battery consumption with a serious percentage, but does it really draw more battery, or does it only "correct" the report?)

Now what should be the way to wait for 2 seconds? Should I continue to use the AlarmManager and garbage collection... Or should I do something like:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

or

```
synchronized (this) {
    try {
        wait(2000);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/regular_updates.html and https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html

Comment: I read those already, that's why I implemented it with AlarmManager. However this service is a FALLBACK service for something that is very important (literally "life and death" can depend on it), so the user knows it'll drain battery but can chose to enable this fallback mode in order to be on the safe side. And still I am trying to do it in the best possible way. I hope my question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Let's set the ground expectation about what battery resources are used for a REST grab.

1. [Battery cost to boot up the Radio chip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9i1_PnPpd3g&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=41) - this is a huge power spike
2. [Battery cost to keep the transfer the data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fEEulSk1kNY&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=13) - this is a long-cost
   based upon the time taken to transfer data.

For these two reasons, there's a lot of other suggestions to handle your implementation.

Firstly, It's recommended to [avoid doing polling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5mE3Tpjejs&index=9&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) in favor of [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). This allows the server to push information to the client ONLY when updates occur. This will cut down on your battery cost signifncantly.

Secondly, if you *can't* use GCM (for example, you down control the server), then you need try and optimize your fetches to occur at better intervals.

1. Adopt a [back-off pattern for your frequency](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orlRuEwlDoM&index=11&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE). if you see that no
   data has updated in the last 2 polls, double the time you wait until
   doing the next poll.
2. Schedule polls to [occur when the radio has already been turned on by someone else](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ecz5WDZoJok&index=10&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE).

I'd recommend using [GCMNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager), which does all this heavy lifting for you. It'll let you set intervals, wait for the radio to be active, and even handle exponential back-off.

Comment: I updated my 1st paragraph to make is clear why I need to poll sometimes. All what you wrote is already implemented.

Comment: If you have back-off-patterns in, then you should only be polling every 2 seconds in situations where the data changes each time. If you have a 10 minute user session, and data is updating every 2 seconds, for-real, then you should be considering something lower-energy like a TCP/UDP socket.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need to use a 3rd party "thing" I can hardly even call API. The only useful information besides the data is the Cache-Control: max-age header, which I use, that's how I got to the +/- 2 sec, Last-Modified, Etag, which lowers the bandwidth a littlebit, when I get 304 response. I measured in the past days, and it looks like polling is even a tiny bit more battery friendly than having an EventSource socket open.